Does lubridate breakdown with large data.frames?
I have a large data.frame of about a million records. I'm trying to use lubridate to fix some dates and I get strange behavior. When I run it on the whole data.frame, it isn't able to parse any records. But when I filter the data.frame based on another missing date column, it manages to parse all but 3. (The 3 is not an issue.) Here is my output.
    > perf3 <- perf2 %>% 
select(first.half, second.half) %>% 
mutate(t.reg.date3=ymd(paste0(first.half, second.half))) 
    Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
    ℹ In argument: `t.reg.date3 = ymd(paste0(first.half, second.half))`.
    Caused by warning:
    ! All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

    > perf3 <- perf2 %>% 
filter(is.na(t.reg.date2)) %>% 
select(first.half, second.half) %>% 
mutate(t.reg.date3=ymd(paste0(first.half, second.half))) 
    Warning: There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
    ℹ In argument: `t.reg.date3 = ymd(paste0(first.half, second.half))`.
    Caused by warning:
    !  3 failed to parse.

Is there some behavior with lubridate where it chokes on large data.frames? Or does it check for ability to parse amongst the first how many records and then gives up? Is there some other aspect I'm missing here?
NB: I haven't been able to create a reproducible example as I can't pin down the rhyme or reason why it does this. This is as pared down as I've been able to get my code. If you have suggestions of where to start to create a reproducible example I welcome them.

It's likely to do with how many unguessable dates there are in each set. ymd help page notes "In case of heterogeneous date formats, the ymd() family guesses formats based on a subset of the input vector. If the input vector contains many missing values or non-date strings, the subset might not contain meaningful dates and the date-time format won't be guessed resulting in ⁠All formats failed to parse⁠ error." - this seems to correspond exactly to what you're reporting

Perhaps if you have a sample head of your dataframe this might help see the range of date formats your data may include?

@AndyBaxter Thank you for this. Yes, this seems to align with what I'm seeing. I actually started with this nested in an if_else statement to filter to the same subset as my filter above, but it still choked. Maybe I'll try to separate and rejoin them directly. (Although I thought that's what dplyr was already doing.)

I can't quite find a way of replicating your error on a synthetic dataset but in theory it should work to select the expected date format manually using e.g. parse_date_time(input_dates, "%Y-%m-%d", exact = TRUE) - this should avoid the 'fail to parse' caused by ymd guessing formats as you specify exactly what data shape you expect to find.

I just tested that code on a vector of 10m dates mixed with fake vars and NAs and it managed it in about 1.5s. Data size shouldn't be an issue if that function helps

Great! This seems to work.

Thanks to @Andy Baxter in the comments. Here is an effective workaround.
> perf3 <- perf2 %>% 
+   select(first.half, second.half, t.reg.date2) %>% 
+   mutate(t.reg.date3=parse_date_time(paste0(first.half, second.half), "%Y-%m-%d", exact = TRUE)) 
Warning message:
There was 1 warning in `mutate()`.
ℹ In argument: `t.reg.date3 = parse_date_time(...)`.
Caused by warning:
!  43047 failed to parse. 

